# Automatic references to Android layout components

Tags: java, android, reflection

I feel like I am constantly repeating this pattern in Android development:

Declare a UI component in a layout

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekTriggerFreq"/>
```

Get a reference using findViewById and casting it

```
SeekBar seekTriggerFreq = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekTriggerFreq);
```

Not a big deal for a few components but it gets cumbersome after a dozen or so. Could this be automated using reflection, Maven or Ant, etc? Maybe a build script that generates a class with static references for you?

Update:
The desired behavior would be similar to how Visual Studio works for its designer. Controls in winforms, xaml, and asp.net are all ready to use without having to manually get a reference. Am I lazy? Yes. But I also know that the more I automate, the fewer bugs I will have.

Comment: Not fully automated, but it does take care of 95% of the boilerplate code: http://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/. Chuck in your layout, adjust the parameters to your coding style and optionally supply a string to redirect the `findViewById()` call on to a specific root view (quite handy if you're i.e. binding up views in a fragment). The remaining 5% is copying and pasting the input/output back and forth. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) is a free, open source library which can replace

```
SeekBar seekTriggerFreq = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekTriggerFreq);
```

with

```
@ViewById
SeekBar seekTriggerFreq;
```

There are many more examples of how to replace boilerplate code with annotations on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare... 
SeekBar seekTriggerFreq;   // Global declaration

and then initialize it..
seekTriggerFreq = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekTriggerFreq); // in any 1st invoking  function so that it gets initialize.. 
and use "seekTriggerFreq" as many times as u want

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now and trying to get around. Seems easy for 1 but after 20 or 30 times it gets boring. It just feels like it could be automated.